# A question about the facets of convex polytopes and their intersections

Tags: convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

Here's an excerpt from M. Ziegler's "Lectures on Polytopes":
[image]
Remarks:

- *polytope* here means what in other sources may be referred to as a *convex polytope* - a convex hull of a finite set of points (vertices);
- $F_1,\dots,F_s$ being a shelling order seems to be irrelevant to the claim (but I'm not sure) , one can probably treat them just as all the facets of $P$.

The highlited claim is given without a proof (as far as I was able to find) also in some other sources on the topic. I see that this is pretty obvious for three or less dimensions. Maybe someone can formalize this claim?

Comment: This is the fact that any $n-2$-face (or *ridge*) of an $n$-polytope is contained in exactly two facets (so nothing to do with shelling). I don't have a convenient reference to hand though.

Comment: I think one can be persuaded of the fact Angina mentions using duality -- every edge in the dual polytope is incident to two vertices.

Comment: This question is now discussed and probably answered over [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3825866/415941).